# How to merge or aggregate multiple web services at attribute level[Not whole responses]

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have tried to merge the two responses which comes from web services by using the apache Camel. In the below code, I have concatenated two responses.

```
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange exchange1, Exchange exchange2) {
        if (exchange1 == null) {
            return exchange2;
        } else {
            String body1 = exchange1.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            String body2 = exchange2.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            String merged = (body1 == null) ? body2 : body1 + "," + body2;
            exchange1.getIn().setBody(merged);
            return exchange1;
        }
    }
```

Here my intention is to pick few attributes from response1 and pick few attributes from response2 , then finalize the final response with attributes which we have picked from response 1 and 2. The final response will be send back to client.

Thanks In Advance.

**Update :** Can we achieve this by using readily available Camel patterns? If not, any ideas or suggestions to write our own algorithm to handle this case.

Comment: show the camel route how do you get these responses

Comment: from(direct:read-service1-info).routeId(direct:read-info)
          .log(" - Fetching aggregated info")
          .multicast(new ReadAggregator())         .parallelProcessing().executorService(readMulticastThreadPoolExecutorService) .to(direct:read-service1-info, direct:read-service2-info)
          .end()

Comment: You want to pick some headers and properties from these exchanges or some fields from body which is JSON, XML or something else?

Comment: I need to pick some fields from body which is a JSON type.

Answer (score 0):

You can get attributes from your JSON body by either:

1. Unmarshaling responses in Camel route before aggregation (at the end of the route `direct:read-service1-info` and the second one) to Java objects, then using them as other Java objects in your aggregate method (`Response1Type response1 = exchange1.getIn().getBody(Response1Type.class)`): [Unmarshalling JSON](http://camel.apache.org/json.html)
2. Using some library to read json inside your aggregate method, for example: [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

Comment: Thanks for your update dey. Will give a try and update.